# How to calculate percentage while matching columns on video_id?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, matching, percentage

I am trying to calculate a percentage of users who view a specific video and those who do not. I managed to calculate the total number of videos and also total number of videos viewed by each group.

However, when I try to calculate the percentages it does not work.
I believe I probably need to match the story ids as the columns do not match anymore after calculating, how do I do that?

This is my formula to calculate percentages:

```
pd.DataFrame(df.status.eq(3).astype(int).groupby(df.story_id).sum() / df['story_id'].value_counts())
```

However the results do not make sense as I believe that during the calculations the `story_id` did not match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For percentage - `sum` divide by `count` is possible use `mean` - solution is simplify:

```
print (df)
   story_id  status
0         1       3
1         1       5
2         1       3
3         2       3
4         2       3
5         4       5
6         4       3
7         5       7


df1 = df.status.eq(3).groupby(df.story_id).mean().reset_index(name='perc')
print (df1)
   story_id      perc
0         1  0.666667
1         2  1.000000
2         4  0.500000
3         5  0.000000
```